# Creating a MacPorts Portfile for a SCons Project

Tags: macports, scons

I want to write a MacPorts Port file for a program typically being installed using SCons.
Usually, I install it by

```
scons build
scons install
```

I managed to create a Portfile which fetches the program and builds it correctly by setting the following flags:

```
depends_build       port:scons

use_configure       no

build.cmd           ${prefix}/bin/scons build
build.target
build.args          prefix=${prefix} \
                    CC=${configure.cc} \
                    CXX=${configure.cxx}
```

This compiles everything nicely in the `build/` subdirectory.

What is the best way to destroot it? Can I make use of the `scons install` routine?

Comment: Take a look at other ports using scons, e.g., `mongodb`, `jsoncpp`, `fife`, `serf1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no general way to do this.

In my case, I ended up doing it by installing the program into the `$destroot` using scons and turning off the usual destroot phase:

```
depends_build       port:scons

use_configure       no

build.cmd           ${prefix}/bin/scons install
build.target
build.args          prefix=${prefix} \
                    CC=${configure.cc} \
                    CXX=${configure.cxx} \
                    python_prefix=${python.prefix} \
                    stage_dir=$destroot

destroot {}
```